# How do I make a bootstrap badge a slightly different color?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a bootstrap badge a different color. I'm a bit new to frontend work, so this is probably an embarrassing question, but I built the following CSS:

```
.badge .badge-danger{
  color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

And added the new CSS after the original one...

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="content/custom.css"/>
```

Yet I see no change! Why?

Comment: It's `.badge.badge-danger` no spaces

Comment: didn't fix sadly

Comment: Ah got it, background-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the badge's background color. **'color'** changes text's color while **'background-color'** is use to change the background of badge.

```
.badge-danger {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #3545dc;
}
```